# No units specified in CSS

Tags: css

I am still new to CSS. In the CSS code below, I have not specified units for height and width. With this, the text fits in one line. When I add px, then the text occupies two lines. What are the units when you specify no units ?

**HTML:**

```
<figure class="hat">
  <img src="http://media.goorin.com/media/catalog/product/cache/1/image/9df78eab33525d08d6e5fb8d27136e95/imports/products/100-3333-BLK-F01.png" width="100" height="100">
  <figcaption>A picture of a hat</figcaption>
</figure>
```

**CSS:**

```
.hat {
  position: relative;
  height: 100;
  width:100;
}
.hat figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> What are the units when you specify no units ?

None. Those declarations are simply invalid.

Any length in CSS *needs* a unit, unless the value is 0.

With your code above, you have effectively not specified width and height at all. (At least in any browser that conforms to the standards.)

Comment: So when the value is zero it's correct to specify just "0" with no units?

Comment: @OMA yes, exactly. No difference between 0 yards and 0 miles.